# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scenePos'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview

Here is my sample code,i want to print the my coordinates of x,y positions by using the mouse press event,i got this error can any one please help me and i want to display the my graphics view in middle of the scrollArea.

Given bellow is my code:

```
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)
        self.row = 2
        self.cols = 4
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(0,0,500,500)
        self.List = []

        for i in range(self.row):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                item = self.scene.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(0,0,30,30))
                item.setPos(30+j*30,500-i*30-60)
                print item.scenePos()
                self.List.append(item)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        super(MyView,self).mousePressEvent(event)
        p = QtCore.QPointF(event.pos())
        print "positonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", p
        item = self.scene.itemAt(p)
        print "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@2"
        print item.scenePos()
class Settings(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Settings, self).__init__(parent)
        spacer = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        spacer.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        self.vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.save = QtGui.QPushButton("save")
        self.open= QtGui.QPushButton("open")
        self.folder= QtGui.QPushButton("Folder")
        self.folder.clicked.connect(self.showSettings)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.save)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.open)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.folder)
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addLayout(self.vbox,0,0)
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Light)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.scrollArea,0,1)
        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setGeometry(200,100,300,300)
        self.show()
    def showSettings(self):
        self.newwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.glayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.newwidget)
        self.MyView =  MyView()
        self.glayout.addWidget(self.MyView,0,1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.newwidget)
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Settings()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ok sir but you told me the previous time don't create a duplicate question just edit the previous question it self so i did like this

Comment: ok sir. I created the new one

Comment: Finally the idea of SO is part is to have a bank of questions and answers that future readers can review in order to solve their own problem saving time (I guess you publish a question before doing a search before to avoid asking the same thing n times ) Therefore, if the question has an accepted answer, the background of the question should not be modified, it should only have drafting improvements, etc., that is, modifications of form but not of substance.

Comment: yes i did searching i am not find how to add a pixmap in  graphics scene, i am getting attribute error i tried the different one set scene then i got my pixmap is added to middle of the area not in rectangles.i.e i posted this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of the items are different to the coordinates of the window, in the case of `event.pos()` returns the position of the mouse with respect to the `viewport` of the `QGraphicsView` so you will have to convert it to coordinates of the scene with `mapToScene()`, by other side when using `itemAt()` could return None since in certain areas of the scene there are no items so it is advisable to verify

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super(MyView,self).mousePressEvent(event)
    p = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
    item = self.scene.itemAt(p)
    if item is not None:
        print(item.scenePos())
```

To understand the different coordinate systems that handle the QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene and the QGraphicsItems, I recommend reading [Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).